# Facebook OAuth 2.0 authentication without using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an app for iOS and Android that uses Facebook to login. The users will login on their phones using their Facebook credentials and I use Facebook's GraphAPI to authenticate them. *I do not want to store their email/password unless I absolutely have to.*

After authentication, I can get a myriad of information from Facebook but the one that's of most interest to my question is the access token's authorization token.

Since my app has a server side component, I also need to validate that this access token is valid on the server side (so given the access token and the Facebook user id, i should be able to validate this client), otherwise the entirety of using Facebook to authenticate users is pointless as I would need to also store username/password of the users myself.

My thought was to send the userId and the access token via SSL to my server and then use a library to validate that these tokens are valid and the user is indeed who it says it is in order to proceed with DB access and everything else server related.

I am however having a hard time finding a library in .NET that does **not** use ASP.NET.

Is there any library out there that can do this simple validation (given an authorization token and a user id, tell me if the user is logged in to Facebook and if so, how long the token is valid for) that does not need to inject 20 different DLLs and does not rely on ASP.NET?

I've had a look at DotNetOpenAuth but (1) it seems to need quite a few DLLs to operate which is kind of fine on its own although not ideal and (2) it seems to rely on ASP.NET and microsoft libraries that I would strongly like to avoid.

I'm running my server on Mono and would ideally like to avoid doing anything with ASP.NET since they have proven to be very unstable in the past.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found an easy way to do it.

First, I downloaded [their .Net library from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Facebook/):

```
<package id="Facebook" version="7.0.6" targetFramework="net40" />
```

Then here's the process in order to authenticate users.

**Step 1**

Get the server's Access Token (this has to be done once at the startup of the service)

```
var client = new FacebookClient
                    {
                        AppId = appId, // get this from developer.facebook
                        AppSecret = appSecret, // get this from developer.facebook
                    };

dynamic appTokenQueryResponse = client.Get("oauth/access_token"
                                            , new
                                                    {
                                                        client_id = appId,
                                                        client_secret = appSecret,
                                                        grant_type = "client_credentials"
                                                    });

_appAccessToken = appTokenQueryResponse.access_token;
```

**Step 2**

With the server access token, We're able to make the appropriate calls into the API in order to make sure the token is valid.

```
private FacebookAuthorizationResponse AuthorizeUser(FacebookClient client, string userId, string accessToken)
{
    dynamic expirationToken = client.Get("debug_token", new
                                                            {
                                                                input_token = accessToken,
                                                                access_token = _appAccessToken
                                                            });

    DateTime expiresAt = DateTimeConvertor.FromUnixTime(expirationToken.data.expires_at);
    bool isValid = expirationToken.data.is_valid;

    if (!isValid)
    {
        return new FacebookAuthorizationResponse
                    {
                        IsAuthorized = false,
                    };
    }

    dynamic response = client.Get(userId, new
                                                {
                                                    access_token = accessToken,
                                                    fields = "id,name"
                                                });

    return new FacebookAuthorizationResponse
                {
                    IsAuthorized = isValid,
                    ExpiresAt = expiresAt,
                    Name = response.name
                };
}
```

Where

---

```
public class FacebookAuthorizationResponse
{
    public bool IsAuthorized { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpiresAt { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a service like https://oauth.io/home which handles that oAUth stuff for you. According to the docs once you set it up you can simply use rest to make authenticated calls. http://docs.oauth.io/#simple-server-side-authorization

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't look to be a C# library. My server is written in C# and doesn't really have any front-end. It's just serving requests to the clients but I need to verify that the client is valid and not some dodgy hacker trying to bypass authentication which is why I need a .NET library that does the authentication. I'm ok writing the HTTP calls myself and parsing the response if need be but I was wondering if there was a library that already did this.